# How to stretch and squeeze an image in PyTorch?

Tags: pytorch, data-augmentation, torchvision

I am working on MNIST Digit Data and looking for a way to either stretch or squeeze the image. The data is of the shape (28,28) and I want the final image to be of the same shape but either stretched or squeezed.

Is there any way to do it using `torchvision.transforms` or using any other method?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [`transforms.RandomAffine`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.RandomAffine).
Stretching and squeezing the image can be done by scaling it.